# React-Native Debugger throws 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, debugging, react-native

My app load perfectly fine on emulator and all the request pass , but on turning on remote debugger, the app could not make api calls to server .

Debugger showing error

```
Failed to load https://mydatapoint/api: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8081' is therefore not allowed access.
```

not sure what is causing the issue .Any help or lead .?

Comment: Can you show me the request header?